# The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api, moss2007enterprisesearch, sharedservicesprovider

I am developing a sharepoint site using sharepoint object model. I am getting "The search request was unable to connect to the Search Service" message on execute **FullTextSqlQuery**. Office Sharepoint Server Search and Indexing Service are running. How can I solve this problem?

Here is code:

```
FullTextSqlQuery qry = new FullTextSqlQuery(SPContext.Current.Site);
qry.QueryText = "SELECT  Path, Title, Rank, Description FROM portal..scope()  Where FREETEXT(*,'\"" + keys + "\"') ORDER BY \"Path\" DESC";
qry.EnableStemming = true;
qry.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
qry.KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords;
qry.AuthenticationType = QueryAuthenticationType.NtAuthenticatedQuery;
ResultTableCollection queryResults = qry.Execute();
ResultTable queryResultsTable = queryResults[ResultType.RelevantResults];
DataTable queryDataTable = new DataTable();
queryDataTable.Load(queryResultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
ResultTable queryResultsTable = queryResults[ResultType.RelevantResults];
DataTable queryDataTable = new DataTable();
queryDataTable.Load(queryResultsTable, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See following:
http://urenjoy.blogspot.com/2009/02/error-search-request-was-unable-to.html